# Eclipse BIRT Report Designer paragraph style different

Tags: eclipse, birt

Let's say I have a bunch of paragraphs coming from a Word file. These paragraphs have different styles applied to them (some are bold, some have smaller or bigger font size, some are italicized, different color, different font-family and so on). Is it possible to add all of these paragraphs into the same Text element in birt and apply the styles that correspond to each paragraph or do I really have to put each paragraph separately into its own Text element and then apply the style to each Text element in birt? Obviously the second approach is more tedious, I would love to find a solution similar to the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the text element content as RTF and apply Paragraph Formatting Tags .

Take a look at [this document](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/ref/ROM_Text_SPEC.pdf) for more information.

Comment: The document talks about texts but it doesn't seem to explain HOW to do what I'm trying to do

Comment: You have to use RTF or HTML inside the text, if you use RTF you can apply Paragraph Formatting Tags to your text ...

Comment: By RTF do you mean Plain Text? Cause I don't see RTF. When I double-click on a text in my report, in the drop-down list in the popup window I see "Auto", "HTML" and "Plain Text"

Comment: you should use HTML even for RTF

Comment: If I use HTML, the style is not applied when I try to view the report in Microsoft Word. Especially the <FONT></FONT> tag

Comment: yeah, I'll give it a try with CSS

Comment: I'm trying to import a css stylesheet in which I have something like: ".mypar{color:red;}", but I keep getting ".mypar - Cannot import style"